# IIS server url rewrite

Tags: iis, webserver

For example, I have a domain `example.com` and my server IP is `1.1.1.1` that is running Microsoft IIS server on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 

The DNS record is `A *.example.com 1.1.1.1`

I want to make the server, `1.1.1.1` display the contents under `C:\inetpub\*`

If the directory doesn't exist, the server should return a 404 error.

For example:

- The file system:

```
|--C:\
    |-- inetpub\
        |-- a
        |-- b
        |-- c
```

will results:

- `a.example.com` **show contents under** `C:\inetpub\a`
- `b.example.com` **show contents under** `C:\inetpub\b`
- `c.example.com` **show contents under** `C:\inetpub\c`
- `d.example.com` **return** `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please map these folders as virtual directory under your website.

For example: /a->c:\inetpub\a.  /b->c:\inetpub\b.

Then you can easily rewrite a.example.com/test.aspx to a.example.com/a/test.aspx. If the folder does not exist. Then d.example.com/d/ will just return 404.

```
<rule name="rewrite">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)\.example\.com" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to remove `a/` in  a.example.com/ **a/** test.aspx ?

Comment: Why would you remove “a/”? a.example.com/a/test.aspx will only be displayed on the server side, and the url in your browser will not contain “a/”